# What will happen if we declare one object and assign it to another object of same class

Tags: java, c++, memory-management, garbage-collection, jvm

Code in C++

```
class FirstClass
{
    public:
        int var;
};

int main()
{
    FirstClass A, B;
    A.var = 10;
    B.var = 20;

    cout << "Address of A : " << &A << endl;
    cout << "A.var : " << A.var << endl << endl;

    cout << "Address of B : " << &B << endl;
    cout << "B.var : " << B.var << endl << endl;

    A = B;

    cout << "Address of A : " << &A << endl;
    cout << "A.var : " << A.var << endl << endl;

    cout << "Address of B : " << &B << endl;
    cout << "B.var : " << B.var << endl << endl;
}
```

OutPut:

Address of A : 0x28fefc

A.var : 10

Address of B : 0x28fef8

B.var : 20

Address of A : 0x28fefc

A.var : 20

Address of B : 0x28fef8

B.var : 20

I know what is going on with memory and value of var. No confusion with above code. Point is that memory remain different and the both objects still referring to same old memory locations. Mean no unreferenced memory.

---

Code in Java;

```
public class FirstClass
{
    public int var;
}


public class SecondClass
{
    public static void main(String str[])
    {
        FirstClass A = new FirstClass();
        FirstClass B = new FirstClass();

        A = B;      
    }
}
```

doing same thing that I have done in above C++ code.
why this time garbage collector will came into action and by doing A = B why we will get a unreferenced memory.

Comment: In Java, A = B, will make A point to the object that is currently pointed by B. It makes the original object that is pointed by A un-referenced, which is eligible for garbage collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's change your code just to give a bit more context:

```
FirstClass A = new FirstClass(1);
FirstClass B = new FirstClass(2);
```

At this point, `FirstClass(1)` and `FirstClass(2)` are not eligible for GC because there are two variable in scope that are currently pointing to these instances. However, when you execute the line:

```
A = B;
```

you make `A` and `B` point to `FirstClass(2)` and "nothing" point to `FirstClass(1)`... and since there's "nothing" pointing to it, `FirstClass(1)` becomes eligible for GC.

Variables in Java are of two kinds. They're either primitive types (e.g. `int`, `boolean`) or are of the `Object` type. Primitive values are always copied on assignment but Object variables just like pointers in C++. If you assign an Object variable to another then you're just changing the memory location that it's pointing to instead of creating a new "copied" instance of the target.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the difference in C++ and Java. When you assign one object to another object in C++, it copies the values of one object to another object. Whereas in Java, it would declare A to be reference to the object pointed to by B. Since now JVM has lost the reference to B and its no more reachable, it becomes eligible candidate for GC.

Comment: +1 for being the only one to understand the C++ side of the question (the question used object assignment in C++, not pointer assignment).

Answer (score 2):

In Java, `A` and `B` are really pointers. But in your C++ code, they're not. That's the only difference.

If you change the C++ `A` and `B` to pointers, you'll see that the two pieces of code are now equivalent:

```
FirstClass* A = new FirstClass;
FirstClass* B = new FirstClass;
A->var = 10;
B->var = 20;

A = B;
```

Now `A = B` copies the pointer, not the pointed-to object, just like in Java.

Answer (score 2):

Trivial object creation in java

```
SomeClass obj = new SomeClass();
```

When you are create a new object using `new` keyword in java as shown above, JVM allocates required memory in the heap area and assign that memory area to the given reference variable, `obj` in our case. So in your cases it allocates memory for 2 objects and assign the reference to the respective reference variables.

When you are doing

```
A = B;
```

We are instructing the JVM to assign the memory reference, referencing by B to the variable A.  So, now both A and  B are pointing to the same memory area.  The other memory area (actually pointed by A, before executing the assignment statement) is not pointed by any reference, hence eligible for garbage collection